# Node js - Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed

Tags: node.js

Error occur when using `SetImmediate()` method.
This is error code.

```
Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed
at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:599:16)
at Immediate.mine (/Volumes/Work/ProjectsByClient/ULC/Exerices/ex6/coinGenerator.js:30:13)
at <anonymous>
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at process.nextTick (internal/child_process.js:603:35)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11)
```

This is my original script

```
mine()

async function mine () {
  const newBlocks = await Bitcoin.mine(miner.pk, miner.sk)
  // console.log(newBlocks)
  if (newBlocks !== null && newBlocks.length > 0) {
    console.log(newBlocks)
    process.send({
      type: 'info',
      newBlocks: newBlocks
    })
  }
  setImmediate(mine)
}
```

This was worked when I didn't use async function, but I must use async function.

Comment: My guess is that you close the parent-process rather quickly after forking. So it did still exist without `assync`, but after doing the function in an `assync` function,  the parent-process doesn't exist anymore at the point you try `process.send`. However, without knowing anything about your parent process, that's just a wild guess.